# How to Access other values from Login Form using Acegi Plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, gigya

I want to pass in other hidden values to the server on the form for login.  Then I want to be able to do some other computations on the server where I have access to the form hidden parameters and also the newly authenticated user object.

I was hoping to use the onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event.  However, I cannot find a pointer to the request object in its params anywhere.

BTW, this is my plan for how to pass information from Gigya to do a linkaccount to a acegi user account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall the exact syntax, but I'm pretty sure we've used the org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder to access request attributes in the security callback methods...

Comment: Hi ecodan,
It sounds like that should work, but I haven't found a syntax that works.  Any chance you could dig up the syntax you are using please?  Do you recall if there was anything else you had to configure to get it to bind the thread value?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer got me looking around in the right place.

org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityRequestHolder.getRequest()

seems to be the best way in the grails plugin to get the request.  Thanks for the help Eocdan.